# css element hidden behind background

Tags: css

I've got this problem where a div is not showing. The code is simple and am testing only:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main</title>

    <style>
        .simple-div {
            -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background:url('backgrounds/cupcakeBG.jpg') 50% -105px repeat;">
    <div style="background: #C8BBBE; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:70px; position: fixed; -moz-border-radius: 15px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;">

    </div>

    <div style="-moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px; height: 200px; width: 200px;">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I keep the second div above the background image? it is currently not showing on screen but I can see it highlighted behind using Inspect element via chrome.

Regards,

Comment: we can't see the background image in your example since it is local to you

Comment: try playing with `position` and `float`

Comment: You don't have any content or background or border colors set, so there's nothing to render. Add `background:#F00;` to your second div, you'll see it then. _I've added it as an answer, since some incorrect ones were coming in.._

Comment: Your second div is not hidden behind your background image, it is hidden behind the first div (which is positioned `fixed`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use position:relative or position:absolute, with a z-index on both divs.

```
<div style="background: #C8BBBE; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:70px; position: fixed; z-index: 0; -moz-border-radius: 15px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;">
</div>

<div style="-moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px; height: 200px; width: 200px; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 15; background-color:#ff0000;">
    test
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

add `position: relative` and `z-index: 9999;` to the div you wish to see on top.

Comment: maybe just z-index: 1 to start?

Comment: yeah, I just threw in a large number to make sure. But start at one.

Comment: Using a large number makes sure the next person has to use a larger number still :)

Answer (score 1):

Your second div contains no content, nor a background, border, etc. so there's nothing to visibly show on the screen. It's there, and it's on top of your body background.

If you also intend to show it on top of your fixed element above, you need it's `z-index` to be higher. You need to give it a `position` that is not `static` for it to use the `z-index` (here, we'll use `relative`):

```
<body style="background:url('backgrounds/cupcakeBG.jpg') 50% -105px repeat;">
    <div style="background: #C8BBBE; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:70px; position: fixed; z-index:1; -moz-border-radius: 15px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;">

    </div>

    <div style="background:#F00; position:relative; z-index:2; -moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px; height: 200px; width: 200px;">

    </div>

</body>
```

Note, in this specific example, the `z-index` can be equal since they are in the same stacking parent, and the fixed div is first. However, it's better to be more explicit, I find, and give the second div an actual higher value.

Answer (score 0):

One option depending on what your goal is to add `position:absolute` to the style attribute of the second div.